# Continuous Integration для PHP. Проясните принцип работы

Tags: php, непрерывная-интеграция

Я прочитал достаточно теории и вроде как понял суть CI. Необходимо оптимально настроить автоматический билд приложения чтобы побыстрее пресечь различного рода ошибки при частой интеграции. Какой еще build для PHP? Насколько я знаю никаких билдов нету. Зачем запускаются разные phploc и прочие программы которые просто возвращают размер проекта. Зачем запускать эти CI сервера? Чем они помогают (в контексте PHP)? Автоматически запускают команды просто?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43001/discussion-on-question-by-vkovalchuk88-continuous-integration--php-).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Постоянная интеграция призвана решать много проблем сразу:

- Исключение человеческого фактора из повторяемых процессов, и, собственно, повторяемость и воспроизводимость этих процессов. Если разработчик может случайно вывалить на продакшен конкретную версию приложения со своими изменениями или забыть в исправленный код отдельной ветке, то постоянная интеграция не дает разработчику это сделать - она устанавливает набор правил и позволяет разработчику пропустить через эти правила свой код, чтобы дать добро на выкладку или отрицательный фидбэк в связи с ошибкой.
- Предыдущий пункт выливается в то, что постоянная интеграция не способна *забыть* какие-либо вещи. В то время как в голове у разработчика умещаются плюс-минус последние две недели, интеграция будет сообщать о проблеме все то время, пока проблема существует.
- Тестирование (с которого, как правило, она начинается). Пока код выкладывается на продакшен без тестирования, никто не может сказать, работает ли он.
- Превращение кодовой базы в артефакт. Кодовая база - это просто текстовые файлы, артефакт - это готовое к работе приложение. В случае с PHP разница между двумя состояниями может быть минимальна и незаметна, но если вы, например, делаете phar-приложение, то непосредственно подготовкой этого phar-архива будет заниматься CI-сервер. Разработчик может несколько раз за день собирать этот архив, но финальную версию собирает машина, и именно она дает гарантии работоспособности архива.
- Автоматизацию процесса релиза проекта до одной кнопки. Разница с предыдущем пунктом тоже может быть не очень хорошо заметна, но артефакт - это просто какая-то сборка приложения, в то время как релиз - это конкретная версия приложения с каким-то функционалом. Сборка артефакта и прогонка тестов гарантируют, что приложение работает, но такой артефакт не обязательно содержит в себе весь функционал, который можно выложить, это может быть промежуточная версия - так, если руководитель запланировал в следующей версии веб-сайта новую админку и интеграцию с какой-нибудь соцсетью, то промежуточный артефакт может содержать что-то одно, а в релиз уходит только такой артефакт, который содержит все запланированное. Кроме того (!sic), релиз может состоять и из нескольких артефактов.
  Сам по себе релиз может быть и автоматическим.
- Полную автоматизацию процесса от выкладки кода в репозитории до выкладки артефактов в продакшен; в отличие от предыдущего пункта, человек полностью  исключается из всей цепочки, а каждая успешная сборка автоматом становится релизом.
- Дополнительные артефакты, такие, как автоматическая документация (пресловутый PHPDoc), подписи артефактов (чтобы конечный получатель мог убедиться в том, что информация о сборке артефактов соотстветствует действительности).
- Дополнительный анализ кода. Тесты - это хорошо, но они говорят исключительно то, работает ли тот код, который был протестирован; они ничего не говорят о том, сколько кода было протестировано и насколько хорош этот код. Поэтому интеграция может включать в себя еще и дополнительные отчеты, например:

  - Общее покрытие кода тестами (e.g. 65% кода покрыто)
  - Отчет о покрытии *конкретных файлов, строк, логических ветвей и выражений*. Здесь начинается самая мякотка, которая может выглядеть [вот так](https://coveralls.io/builds/7098857/source?filename=yapf%2Fyapflib%2Ffile_resources.py) - вы просто физически видите, какие строки и в каких тестах были покрыты. Более того, такие отчеты отлично интегрируются с IDE, что позволяет вам отслеживать подобные штуки на своей машине (оставляя CI для мониторинга общего тренда - покрытие растет или падает)
  - Человекочитаемые отчеты о тестах. Когда вы тестируете код, вы формализуете проблему до сравнения реального результат с желаемым, и ошибка 'Failed asserting that 42 is true' или 'Failed asserting that server returned 200' вам ничего не скажет. Однако есть специальные фреймворки, позволяющие вам сгенерировать еще более вкусную мякотку с человеческими описаниями тестами (что мы тестируем? почему появился этот тест? что происходило во время теста? какой *use-case* проверяется в ходе этого теста?), прикладывать к ним аттачменты, мерять скорость выполнения тестов (если какой-то из них подвисает, то хорошо знать какой, верно? этакий test-insght). Конкретно сейчас я описываю мой любимый [allure](http://ci.qatools.ru/job/allure-core_master-deploy/127/Allure_report/index.html#behaviors/2d85d46a1d92bd6b/90e912877b8901ec), но кроме него наверняка есть еще непочатый край утилит. Не пожалейте времени, сходите по ссылке - представляете, насколько вы упростите жизнь в сложном проекте, если к каждому проваленному тесту будет прилагаться (sic!) скриншот страницы, на которой не удалось совершить ожидаемые действия, список шагов, которые должны были быдь пройдены в тесте, конкретный браузер, в котором появились проблемы, и, наконец, какая-нибудь несмешная шутка?
  - Отчеты о статическом анализе кода. Это очередная мякотка, которая надает вам по рукам, если вы строите слишком сложные циклы или пишете нечитаемый код. В то время как анализ реализации логики - это AI-complete задача (после решения которой программисты не очень и нужны, потому что логику может писать сама система), анализ правильно расставленных отступов, повторяемого кода и количества комментариев - это вполне разрешимая задача. Чтобы еще раз впечатлить вас, оставлю очередную [ссылку](https://codeclimate.com/github/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/Gitlab::UserAccess?from_sha=de204b95&to_sha=71b8ca03), а чуть позже вернусь к этой теме.
  - Автоматические ченджлоги и отчеты о вкладе команды в проект. Это уже очень специфичная и сложная тема, которой я не касался.
  - Нагрузочное и прочее тестирование, приближенное к реальной жизни и не тестирующее код напрямую (в нетфликсе, например, не пропускают релизы, которые по показателям производительности хуже предыдущих и намеренно убивают серверы, чтобы проверить жизнеспособность системы в критических ситуациях). Если нас интересует конечный продукт, то почему бы не автоматизировать еще и проверку того, что он будет соответствовать нашим ожиданиям скорости?
- Проверку возможности слияния двух источников кода до реального слияния
- И, наконец, постоянная интеграция легко интегрируется (pun intended) с различными способами оповещения разработчиков. Следить за процессом билда - утомительное и ненужное дело, поэтому постоянную интеграцию можно настроить на уведомление только в тех случаях, когда изменения что-то ломают; в этом случае молчание системы автоматически означает, что либо все работает, либо интеграция тупо сдохла (это решается мониторингом, который я не буду здесь затрагивать).

Весь набор задач - создать артефакт, прогнать тесты, прогнать анализ - называется пайплайном, а однократное прохождение кодом пайплайна - билдом. Билд - это сам факт прохождения кодом постоянной интеграции, результатом которого могут быть вышеописанные артефакты и отчеты.

Как это все помогает проекту? Представим, что у нас есть некоторый виртуально-бесконечный проект с гигантским числом разработчиков, которых невозможно контролировать физически. Если у вас нет вышеописанного пайплайна, у вас нет возможности заглянуть в код и оценить состояние текущей кодовой базы, технического долга и вклада разработчиков в проект. На маленьких проектах это может настолько же виртуально-бесконечно не стрелять в ногу, но в случае с большим проектом это уже не прокатит, потому что начинают появляться следующие ситуации:

- В продакшен ушел битый релиз с багами. В ходе разработки новых фич разработчики затронули старый код и все сломали. Кто виноват? Кто внес баг? Кто пропустил этот баг?
- Разработчики говорят, что нужен срочный рефакторинг. Как оценить, насколько он нужен, как расставить приоритеты при рефакторинге, где находятся наиболее горячие места?
- Разработчики говорят, что проект недопокрыт тестами и грозятся рисками выкатки нерабочего релиза. Как определить, правда ли это?
- Разработчики говорят, что у нас в целом ухудшается кодовая база. Опять клянчат рефакторинг, или все действительно идет по наклонной?
- Другие ситуации, для которых иссякла моя фантазия

Суммируя все вышенаписанное, CI дает вам возможность автоматизировать все рутинные процессы, перенести основные задачи тестирования на машину, нормализовать диалог между менеджерами / разработчиками / отделом качества продукта и проанализировать кодовую базу буквально что изнутри. Пока у вас нет этой штуки, вы не знаете, в каком состоянии текущий продукт, поэтому берете на себя все риски выпуска нерабочего продукта, внезапно открывшейся необходимости рефакторинга, траты времени на бэктрейс багов, возникающих в системах со сложной логикой. Безусловно, это не панацея, и баги, на которые не были написаны тесты, все равно уйдут в продакшен, но без всей этой штуки вы вообще не можете заглянуть внутрь и отследить техническое (и, возможно, не только) качество продукта.

Касаясь вашего конкретного примера с PHPLoc - он действительно бесполезен, если просто использовать его для подсчета веселых цифр. Но косвенно он дает вам способ проанализировать ваше приложение:

- Каков объем кодовой базы? *Если мы берем нового разработчика, с каким объемом кода ему придется ознакомиться, чтобы начать работать*?
- Сколько у нас глобальных констант? *Не работают ли у нас макаки?*
- Что у нас с цикломатической сложностью? *Корректно ли у нас разносится логика в коде?*

Если в проекте участвуете только вы, и вы совершенно точно не используете глобальные константы, то он вам не нужен. Но если вы работаете в стартапе, где каждый день на счету, и зачастую вам приходится жертвовать качеством в угоду скорости, то вместо расставления todo по всему проекту вы можете мониторить те грязные участки кода, которые пришлось оставить, с помощью тех же phploc, phpcs, phpmd. Вопрос о том, насколько это нужно вашему текущему проекту - открытый, но сама возможность предоставить этот самый взгляд на код изнутри у вас есть.

Для закрепления впечатления - [еще одна ссылка](http://ci.qatools.ru/job/allure-core_master-deploy) на CI вышеупомянутого Allure. Его разрабатывает команда автоматизации тестирования в Яндексе, и там можно посмотреть, как проходит билд - там есть и прогонка тестов, и тренды, и автоматический анализ качества через sonarqube.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43002/discussion-on-answer-by-etki-continuous-integration--php---).

Answer (score 2):

в формат коммента не попадает, поэтому ответом оформлю.

phploc

```
Directories                                          3
Files                                                8

Size
  Lines of Code (LOC)                             1858
  Non-Comment Lines of Code (NCLOC)               1298 (69.86%)
```

Автоматические отчет проджект менеджеру о том, что програмисты работают, а не ваньку валяют

```
  Comment Lines of Code (CLOC)                     560 (30.14%)
```

Покрытие комментами. Есть практика, что хороший код должен быть самодокументируемым. 30% - это дохрена

```
  Logical Lines of Code (LLOC)                     289 (15.55%)
    Classes                                        260 (89.97%)
      Average Class Length                          37
      Average Method Length                          9
```

Динамика показывает выполняемость принципа единственной ответственности

```
    Functions                                        5 (1.73%)
      Average Function Length                        5
    Not in classes or functions                     24 (8.30%)
```

ООП или функциональный? Отклонения сигнализируют об отходе от гайдлайнов

```
Complexity
  Cyclomatic Complexity / LLOC                    0.67
  Cyclomatic Complexity / Number of Methods       7.86
```

тут промолчу

```
Dependencies
  Global Accesses                                    2
    Global Constants                                 2 (100.00%)
    Global Variables                                 0 (0.00%)
    Super-Global Variables                           0 (0.00%)
```

Чем больше - тем хуже

```
  Attribute Accesses                                48
    Non-Static                                      48 (100.00%)
    Static                                           0 (0.00%)
  Method Calls                                      96
    Non-Static                                      91 (94.79%)
    Static                                           5 (5.21%)
```

думаю и так понятно.

Дальше лень разбирать

```
Structure
  Namespaces                                         4
  Interfaces                                         0
  Traits                                             0
  Classes                                            7
    Abstract Classes                                 0 (0.00%)
    Concrete Classes                                 7 (100.00%)
  Methods                                           28
    Scope
      Non-Static Methods                            28 (100.00%)
      Static Methods                                 0 (0.00%)
    Visibility
      Public Method                                 10 (35.71%)
      Non-Public Methods                            18 (64.29%)
  Functions                                          1
    Named Functions                                  0 (0.00%)
    Anonymous Functions                              1 (100.00%)
  Constants                                          1
    Global Constants                                 1 (100.00%)
    Class Constants                                  0 (0.00%)
```

Если для вас ничего из этого контролировать не интересно - да ради бога, тогда забудьте про него и не используйте.

Comment: *Есть практика, что хороший код должен быть самодокументируемым. 30% - это дохрена* — если это именно поясняющие комментарии. Я нередко оставляю в комментариях шутки. Метрики несовершенны :) но это так, ерунда, в целом соображения правильное.

Comment: СI это вопрос сбора статистики просто? Нет, я так не думаю. Генерация отчетов проджект менеджерам это не CI.    Continius integration это побыстрее пофиксить если я увижу что код нерабочий попал в мастер , какие то баги появились, что мне с этих метрик? Мне безразлично сколько там комментариев .
Единственное полезное насколько я понимаю это покрытие тестами и то если ты знаешь что они покрывают все

Comment: Та они не то что несовершенны а вообще бесполезны в плане continuous integration что мне что я посмотрел на эти циферки, чтобы пользователи ваньку не валяли надо тайм трекинг какой то или что

Answer (score 1):

Могут быть несколько серверов, на которые должны попасть обновления, так же, как правило, используются тесты — они запускаются сразу после коммита, проверяют и оценивают качества кода, собирают метрики, генерируется документация, позволяют сразу определять проблемы слияния веток и т.д.