# репозиторий синхронизирует не все файлы

Tags: git, gulp

Почему репозиторий воспринимает не все изменения?
Есть допустим такая структура:

```
-css
-sass
index.html
```

после внесения изменения в файл sass gulp генерирует css. Так вот измененный sass виден в изменениях а сгенерированный css нет. 
Кто скажет в чем может быть проблема?

Git GUI - Github Desktop

Comment: Как я понимаю это может возникать из файла .gitignore
В нем может быть прописан каталог или файлы которые git должен игнорировать.

Comment: потому что вновь сгенерированый css-файл нужно добавить в отслеживание новых файлов git

    git add your-css-file 
Если я правильно понял

Comment: Всем спасибо! Оба комментария выше оказались верными! Исправил файлик и все пошло!!!!

Comment: @alexandrovdi жду от вас ответа. Наверняка вам есть что уточнить или вы с чем-нибудь не согласны.

Answer (score 5):

Если вы генерируете CSS из SASS, то вам вообще не нужно версионировать CSS, потому что в данном случае это *артефакт сборки*, а не *исходный код*. Это подобно тому, чтобы включать в репозиторий скомпилированную программу с каждым коммитом. Или в книгу рецептов заливать борщ и котлеты. Недостатки такие:

- Лишние данные повышают размер репозитория.
- Изменения видны сразу в двух местах — в исходнике и в артефактах. При этом артефакты-то никто руками не менял.
- Неочевидно, куда изменения вносить — в CSS или SASS.

Вероятнее всего, папка `css` добавлена в файл `.gitignore`, чтобы git её не отслеживал. Это неспроста (см. предыдущий параграф).

> Исправил файлик и все пошло

Зря, исправьте обратно.

Вам явно нужно доставлять CSS на сервер в процессе деплоя (развертывания). Похоже, вы пытаетесь деплоить через git — именно для этого приходится добавлять CSS в git. Не делайте так, это неэффективный и небезопасный подход. Вместо этого [доставляйте сгенерированные файлы сайта с помощью `rsync`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428514/181472).

Сборку CSS из SASS с помощью gulp вообще можно и нужно автоматизировать. Начать вы можете с доработки задачи gulp — добавьте ещё одну для публикации через rsync и вам не придётся делать это руками. Вместо этого будете писать что-нибудь вроде

```
gulp build
# тут проверили локально, что всё хорошо
gulp publish
# тут работает rsync
```

Полную автоматизацию можно сделать с помощью сервера [непрерывной интеграции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470453/181472), подключенного к репозиторию. Если проект у вас на GitHub, то вы можете подключить Travis CI и собирать на нём. Он бесплатен для опенсорса. Вот пример конфига для сборки проекта на Node.js с помощью Travis CI: [JavaScript (with Node.js)](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/)

Про различие исходников и артефактов [неплохо рассказал Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547250/181472).